# vue3 chart.js Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')

Tags: chart.js, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue3 and Chart.js and I couldn't figure out how to solve this issue. I'm keep getting the same error over and over. Can someone please help me?

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
```

Here is my template:

```
<template>
<div class="border border-dark rounded container m-2">
     <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
</template>
```

and my script:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto' 

export default {
mounted() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');        
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    console.log('mounted')
}
```

And I have one more question, when I run this code I get null. Is this normal?

```
console.log(document.getElementById("myChart"))
```

Comment: There's a wrapper for `Chart.js` called [vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org/) that supports Vue 3, have you considered using it?